# Posting an object with list of strings

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using RestSharp 110.2.0 on .Net 7

Everything works fine if I "AddStringBody", however I cannot seem to add an object using "AddJsonBody".

This is the body that works (ie though Talend API Tester)

```
{
  "ApiRequest": {
    "TransactionId": "1234",
    "Version":"",
    "TestGUIDs": ["c1c1ee44-6ae1-485b-bb4e-8ca4a4837830"]
  }
}
```

This code works as expected:

```
        string stringBody = @"
            {
              ""ApiRequest"": {
                ""TransactionId"": ""1234"",
                ""Version"":"""",
                ""TestGUIDs"": [""c1c1ee44-6ae1-485b-bb4e-8ca4a4837830""]
              }
            }";

        restRequest.AddStringBody(stringBody, ContentType.Json);
```

This does not:

```
 QGRequest qGRequest = new QGRequest
            {
                ApiRequest = new ApiRequest
                {
                    TransactionId = "1234",
                    Version = "",
                    TestGUIDs = new List<string> { "c1c1ee44-6ae1-485b-bb4e-8ca4a4837830" }

                }
            };

            restRequest.AddJsonBody(qGRequest);
```

I have tried all kinds of variations on this, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to add the JSON content that is generated by the `RestRequest` object, when you use `AddJsonBody()`.

Comment: My guess would be that the `AddJsonBody` also changes property names to camel case... but it's hard to tell from the current question description.

Comment: So, I am getting a Bad Request response from the server.

Comment: So, doing it this way works:  restRequest.AddStringBody(JsonSerializer.Serialize(qGRequest), ContentType.Json);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see in the [docs](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#json):

> By default, RestSharp will use `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web` configuration. If necessary, you can specify your own options.

Looking up what `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web` is about in [.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializerdefaults?view=net-7.0#fields):

> `Web`
> Option values appropriate to Web-based scenarios.
> This member implies that:
>
> - Property names are treated as case-insensitive.
> - **"camelCase"** name formatting should be employed.
> - Quoted numbers (JSON strings for number properties) are allowed.

Apparently, your payload is expected to be Pascal-case. It can easily be done by changing using `JsonSerializerDefaults.General` by setting the serialiser options as shown in the docs:

```
var client = new RestClient(options, 
    configureSerialization: s => s.UseSystemTextJson(new JsonSerializerOptions())
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into that.   The api's I am calling are not the best that I have seen.  For example they REQUIRE "CustomField1", "CustomField2", ect. to be there.   In the mean time, just building the string and doing: restRequest.AddStringBody(requestBody, ContentType.Json);  works

Comment: You can annotate the properties with `JsonPropertyName` attribute if you need to override the defaults. System.Text.Json is a comprehensive and well-documented serialiser.